# What are suitable dimensions for a router table that specifically would be used to make an acoustic guitar?

Tags: mdf, router-table

I was wondering what the optimal size is for a router table for making an acoustic guitar? Initially I would use it to help me make some jigs to bend guitar sides and hold the parts together as I shape the body.

I was thinking 800mm x 600mm, but now I think this might be oversized for this purpose. I plan to make the table top from MDF and laminate with Formica offcuts.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. As I'm fond of saying, don't reinvent the wheel — I'd suggest the ideal course of action for someone in your position would be to find our what size of router table other makers of acoustic guitars use. I say size but I should say size**s** because I'm certain you'll find there's a surprisingly wide range, rather than a sort of sweet spot of say around the size you're thinking (for all sorts of reasons, but perhaps mostly because almost nobody will use the router table for this alone).

Comment: Failing being able to find the above info out you could easily prototype this with just a simple drilled hole in some ply or MDF (unlaminated, just the basic board) and see how you get on with it. If your prototype seems to do the trick make a fancier one the same size. Simples.

Comment: There are 284,987  YouTube videos on making router tables. (*i made that number up*) https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=diy+router+table

Answer (score 1):

You want it to be big enough to support the pieces you'll be working with, but not so big that it's hard to reach where the bit sticks through.

- If you have to stretch to reach the bit, you'll be off balance and could hurt yourself.
- If you have to juggle the piece you're routing, it'll likely slip, possibly damaging the work.

I'd suggest taking a look at some commercially available tables to see what sizes they come in - something in that range would most likely work for you unless there's something *really* special about guitar making. If there is, it would help if you would edit that into your original question so we may be able to help address that.